# Accessing SSRS Report from external URL (ISA Server) doesn't render

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with parameters accessible by two URLs. 
One URL is using the internal servername and one is an address defined in the Microsoft ISA Server.

When I am connected to the local network both URLs are working correctly. When I want to access the report by the ISA URL from an external network just the parameters will be rendered and the report content is empty. In the SSRS Execution Logs I can't find a record that I executed the report when I access the report by the ISA address.

The funny thing is, that I fill a parameter list based on the users login name. This list is filled correctly.

Any ideas?

Many thanks
Andi

Comment: What's the authentication when you are coming in from the external network.  I'm gathering you don't have a Windows user in this case, so that is why the filled parameter list is surprising?

Comment: It's Windows Authentication and Windows users are accessing the report. Theses users are member of the Browser role.

Comment: In the report I am using the user login (User!UserID) to fill the parameter list by query. The parameterlist was loaded correctly.

Comment: OK, one network administrator told me that something with ISA authentication is wrong. I will post the solution when I got more informations.

Comment: Thanks, I keep running into these authentication problems, and I'd love to know what the solution was in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This patch solved the problem

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940248/en-us